# How to select usernames start with a-to-c range in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I got a table with username. I want to select username starts with a to c. What is the SQL syntax for this in PostgreSQL? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of different ways, but I'd probably use a regular expression with a character set match:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ~ '^[a-cA-C]';
```

or a substring search:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE lower(left(username,1)) BETWEEN 'a' AND 'c';
```

In older versions of PostgreSQL the `left` function isn't available, so you have to use `substring(username from 1 for 1)` instead.

See [string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) and [pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) for more information.